# octave: add gdal support for mapping package

Tags: mapping, gis, octave, gdal

I am trying to run some old matlab code with octave. Unfortunately this code contains a `geotiffread` function and I think I should change this function with [`rasterread`](https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/function/rasterread.html) (package [mapping](https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/index.html)).
However, when I try to install the `mapping` package I get this warning:

```sh
octave:7> pkg install mapping-1.4.0.tar.gz 
configure: WARNING: GDAL library not found.  Reading of raster files will be disabled.
For information about changes from previous versions of the mapping package, run 'news mapping'.
```

I tried to run octave (5.2.0 version) within:

- a Debian Buster distribution (snap and flatpak package)
- a docker container (MacOS 10.15 host, installed from the [mtmiller/octave](https://hub.docker.com/r/mtmiller/octave) image).
- online with the [octave-online](https://octave-online.net/) service, running this code:

```sh
pkg load mapping;
[bands, info] = rasterread ('mexutm250.tiff');
```

With this output:

```sh
octave:3> source("my_script.m")
error: gdalread: reading of raster file with GDAL was disabled during installation
error: called from
    rasterread at line 56 column 26
    my_script at line 2 column 15
```

No attempt was successful.

---

EDIT 2: I know that my octave installations are without GDAL support. I would like to use octave with full `mapping` package, and GDAL support, without recompile it. There is a way to do it (e.g. update a library path within the docker installation to add the `libgdal` library)?

If there is no way to add GDAL support without recompile octave, there is a guide to do it with minimal effort?

EDIT 3: I already installed the gdal dependencies:

```sh
$ sudo aptitude search gdal |grep ^i
[sudo] password for virtuser: 
i  gdal-bin - Geospatial Data Abstraction Library - programmi di utilità
i A gdal-data - libreria Geospatial Data Abstraction Library - file di dati
i  libgdal-dev - libreria Geospatial Data Abstraction Library - file di sviluppo
i  libgdal20 - libreria Geospatial Data Abstraction Library
```

Thank you.

Comment: You should read the WARNING after the intall procedure... "Reading of raster files will be disabled. For information about changes from previous versions of the mapping package, run 'news mapping'."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got octave with GDAL integration when I installed the octave package from the debian repository. I needed octave 5.2, so I switched to Ubuntu 20.04.

Answer (score 0):

as suggested in one of the comments, checking

```
>> news mapping
```

(also at https://octave.sourceforge.io/mapping/NEWS.html)

looking at mapping 1.2.1 where rasterread was introduced, it states:

> ** New features
>         Reading GIS raster data:  A first go is provided using
>         functions rasterread.m and rasterinfo.m.  Both invoke binary
>         function gdalread() of which an initial version was provided
>         by Shashank Khare.  rasterread.m and rasterinfo.m can read
>         and return info on any raster data type that the underlying
>         GDAL library can read.  As such, separate functions for e.g.,
>         GeoTIFF and ArcGrid etc. are not required.
>         To make use of these functions the GDAL library must be
>         present on your system => GDAL is a suggested dependency.

You should be able to install [the GDAL library](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/gdal-bin) in Debian using your preferred installation method.

Unsure whether or not you'll need to uninstall/reinstall the mapping package afterward, but if an unload/reload doesn't get rid of the message, try that and see if mapping is able to see the library.